# YQL functionality with Javascript implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yql

I am using this `Ajax` call to grab a CSV file from the Internet. Currently the way that it is implemented is with a call to `yahooapis` and a `SQL` like query of the file.

```
function getData(qry){
          $.ajax({
                url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
                data: { 
                    q: qry,
                    format: 'json',
                    _maxage: 120,
                    ts: getTS(dateNow)
                },
                cache:true,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success:function(data){  
                    setFlowData(data);      
                }   
            });
        }
```

The `qry` is similar to something like this:

```
select * from csv where url IN ('http://example.com/public/zone.csv')
```

The file is then parsed by a function similar to this:

```
if(data.query.count > 0){ 
        var queryData = data.query.results.row;
        if (queryData.col2 == rt.id) {  
            rt.lbmp = queryData.col3;
            rt.ts = queryData.col0;
        }       
    }
```

My question is how do I achieve the same functionality without the use of the YQL/SQL call? Is this possible with `JavaScript` implementation? Thanks for the help.

Comment: What are you trying to do? The yql call goes to the server, the server looks at your query and parameters and builds the returned data. If thats the only way to form that data then that's the way you are stuck with. Why is it even a problem??

Comment: Because I was tasked with eliminating the need for YQL in the system @Spacedman. I would love to keep this, but unfortunately I need to find a way to eliminate our need for it.

Comment: I don't think anyone can help unless you at least tell us what `qry` you are passing to this.

Comment: @Spaceman i added the query. It is simply a call to a file which is then parsed by another method.

Comment: So do you simply want to get the whole of the csv file into a JS variable? YQL is just doing csv->json for you? So you just need a parser... goog... https://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/

Comment: I'm sorry my question isn't up to your standards @Spacedman. I believe it is clear what I am asking. You cannot directly replace the `url` in the ajax call with a csv file. All I ask is how to attain a CSV file from the internet with the same functionality as I have now, with JavaScript. I realize I need to parse the file afterwards, but that wasn't part of my question

Comment: If the CSV is not on your server then you'll need some kind of interface like YQL using jsonp to get over the cross-domain security issues - can you run a local proxy so a query to the server host can jump though and get the csv from the remote one?

Comment: No the files are not on our servers. What do you mean by "...some kind of interface like YQL..."? Does this mean that this is not possible with the current JavaScript/jQuery library and I do in fact need to find another such service as YQL?

Comment: Also @Spacedman code.google.com/p/jquery-csv doesn't take CSVs as input, only plain text in CSV form.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely you can process CSV data without any YQL stuff. You can use $.ajax to pull csv data if it is from your own domain or CORS-ready, or through CORS proxy server. There is also jquery-csv(https://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/) or PapaParse(http://papaparse.com/) to parse CSV data.

Comment: "...if it is from your own domain..." - what if it isn't :(

Comment: "domain" can be considered as synonyms of "protocol://wwww.yourhost.com" part of url, or origin source of a web site.

For security reason, ajax call to other domain (=cross origin access) is usually blocked by browser intently, unless third party server enable "cross origin access" explicitly. There is also a popular ajax proxy pattern (ajax call through a intermediate private or public proxy server). Please search "cross origin ajax" or CORS for more infromation.